# Selenium Select Hidden Drop Down Menu

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors

Good afternoon everyone,

So my issue is I am trying to select fields in drop down menu's that are hidden. Below is the HTML code for one of the said drop down menus.

```
<div id="mainForm:defectPriorityField" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:120px">
<div class="ui-helper-hidden">
<select id="mainForm:defectPriorityField_input" name="mainForm:defectPriorityField_input">
<option value="1-Urgent">1-Urgent</option>
<option value="2-Very High">2-Very High</option>
<option value="3-High">3-High</option>
<option value="4-Medium">4-Medium</option>
<option value="5-Low">5-Low</option>
</select>
```

Now I have read there are a couple ways I can do this. Below seeming to be the most popular.

```
String cssSelector= ...
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+cssSelector+"\');");
    stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
    js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

The xpath for the drop down menu is //*[@id="mainForm:defectPriorityField_input"]
I am relatively new to this and am unsure how to generate or get a cssSelector. Please if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the correct approach would be to actually click on the drop down menu to display the options at which point they're no longer hidden and can easily select them. Have you tried doing it that way?

Comment: Yes I can do this, but I have another problem doing this, some of the drop down menu's are dynamic and what is in them is changing. And the only way to select the item in the drop down is by its xpath. Which is always changing depending on if the drop down increased in size etc.

Comment: I originally was going to do this.
    Select parameterSelectField = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("mainForm:defectPriorityField_input")));
    parameterSelectField.selectByVisibleText("5-Low");

But since it is a hidden field select method will not work.

Comment: Hidden fields will not work with selenium you'll have to use some crafty js which i've personally never been able to get to work but others have had success so perhaps you'll have more luck than i have.

Comment: The dynamic drop downs you refer to i would imagine are not random right? do they have text you can key off of or a previous selection that controls what they contain?

Comment: Correct they are not random, but new fields could be added removed etc. from the drop down menus. The way they are setup though you cannot do a say driver.findElement(by.  because of the types of names they are given or how they are dynamically setup.

Comment: So what's 'random' about it? The `select`'s ID? The `option` values? The outer `div` ID? What? Please show us *two* examples of the HTML, so we can see what is different. There is *usually* something you can 'hook' into.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the approach I'd take which is to first click on the drop down menu then select an option:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"mainForm:defectPriorityField\"]);
dropdown.click();

WebDriverWait waitForOptions = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
waitForOptions.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"mainForm:defectPriorityField_input\"]")));

WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=\"mainForm:defectPriorityField_input\"]/option[text()=\"1-Urgent\"]"));
option.click();
```

Please excuse any syntax errors but that's essentially the idea. In the last statement for the option element you can substitute the text "1-Urgent" with a variable or whatever you like.

Comment: Unfortunetly this did not work, received following error. After fixing the minor syntax issues.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id=\"mainForm:defectPriorityField_input\"]/option[text()=\"1-Urgent\"]"}

Comment: When you run your program are you actually able to see whether the drop down menu is displayed? If you stick that xpath into firebug does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If an element is Hidden, you should not be using it. As the user would not either.

If it is not then why not use the SelectElement?

```
    SelectElement sel = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("Id")));
    sel.SelectByValue("Value");
```

Comment: This is not true the drop down menu is visible on the web page. The Select version of the element is hidden and only the label id and div id are visible so the Select class and methods throw an error.